# create crosstab in java and display in Jpanel

Tags: java, jpanel, crosstab

I'm working on report generation and using the jasper report for generating report but the output of  the jasper report is displaying  in JRViewer or JasperViewer. Is it possible to view the jasper report on Jpanel?

I also using JFreechart for generating reports, but in the Jfreechart api, crosstab generation is not happening.

How do I display the output in JPanel?

Comment: [Display Cross tab in JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147140/display-cross-tab-in-jpanel)?

Comment: You can export the report to a `BufferedImage`

Comment: BufferedImage is ok for Bar Graph and Line chart but for crosstab we need to display the crosstab inon own Jpanel and Should be copy in the form of RTF format

Comment: The output of the report would generally be the same for both print and `BufferedImage` (and probably RTF as well). Are you intending to allow the user to manipulate the report?